# GCP stackdriver logging logs format changed in bucket from folder per container to stdout\stderr

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

i have a question, similar as describe here: [GKE kubernetes container stdout logs format changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305955/gke-kubernetes-container-stdout-logs-format-changed)

in old version of stackdriver i had 1 sink with filter like this:

```
resource.type=container,
resource.namespace_id=[NAMESPACE_NAME] 
resource.pod_id=[POD_NAME]
```

and logs was stored in bucket pretty well, like this:

```
logName=projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/[CONTAINER-NAME]
```

...so i had folders whith logs for each container.

But now i updated my stackdriver logging+monitoring to last version and now i have 2 folders stdout\stderr which contains all logs for all containers!

```
logName=projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/stdout
logName=projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/stderr
```

All logs from many containers stored in this single folders! This is pretty uncomfortable =(

I'v read about this in docs: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#changes_in_log_entry_contents

> The logName field might change. Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring log entries use stdout or stderr in their log names whereas Legacy Stackdriver used a wider variety of names, including the container name. The container name is still available as a resource label.

...but i can't find solution! Please, help me, how to make container per folder logging, like it was in old version of stackdriver?

Comment: It looks like expected behavior described in the documentation. If you need some functions that aren't available at the moment you can try to create `Feature Request` at Google Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=1162662

Comment: Not sure, that this function not exist, maybe i'm just not find proper solution yet.

Comment: Maybe need to use "Sink Service/Custom destination" instead of "Sink Service/Cloud Storage", and make somehow folders, which can be created depends on Labels, for instance

storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET-NAME/%resource.labels.container_name%

Comment: I've attach link to Google Issue Tracker with a possible workaround https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149300373 and already opened Feature Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround that has been suggested:

1. Create a different sink for each of your containers filtered by
   resource.labels.container_name
2. Export each sink to a different
   bucket

**Note**: If you configure each separate sink to the same bucket the logs will be combined.

More details at [Google Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/149300373)

Comment: this seems like the only solution at the moment
also guys from google say the same https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149300373