# GKE Stackdriver logName is [container_name] instead of stdout

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

According to documentation: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/migration

*The logName field might change. Cloud Operations for GKE log entries use stdout or stderr in their log names whereas Legacy Logging and Monitoring used a wider variety of names, including the container name. The container name is still available as a resource label.*

I have GKE version `1.17.9-gke.1504` Cloud Operations for GKE is **enabled**. Legacy Logging is **disabled** and I have in logs:

```
labels: {
  ...
  container_name: "controller"
  project_id: "aaa"
 }
}
...
logName: "projects/aaa/logs/controller"
```

The question is why not `logName: "projects/aaa/logs/stdout"`? Is there any configuration parameter responsible for that? I would like to have **stdout** as a log_id and not **controller** cause other parts of the system depends on that.

Comment: Do you have nodepool with legacy endpoints disabled ?  Did you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305955/gke-kubernetes-container-stdout-logs-format-changed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177065/gcp-stackdriver-logging-logs-format-changed-in-bucket-from-folder-per-container ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, I have one nodepool with legacy endpoints disabled. But still I have `resource.type=k8s_container` and `logName=projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/logs/[CONTAINER-NAME]`

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: It looks like GCP is switching between fluent-bit and fluentd on my cluster, without any reason known to me. And `logName` configuration is different in those tools. My solution is to turn off default logging and configure my own fluent-bit with custom configuration. This way I have a full control over `logName`.